# How to Parse XML data from .ASHX handler and Display it in gridView in android

Tags: android, xml, web-services, xml-parsing

Actually i m working on webservices. I have been provided a link Like `http://www.url.com/requesthandler.ashx.` now I have to access the data from this link and display it in my custom gridView which contains a textView and a ImageVIew.

i m getting the response from given URL in XML format as shown below.

```
<Result><Status>OK</Status><SearchedText>in</SearchedText><Books><Book><BookID>161</BookID><BookCode>EN161</BookCode><BookTitle>A Brief History of the Fourteen Infallibles</BookTitle><BookAuthor>Anonymous</BookAuthor><DatePublished>5/18/2012 12:00:00 AM</DatePublished><CPID>23</CPID><StatusID>168</StatusID><CPName>Kazim.Homayee</CPName><CPEmail>kazim.homayee@gmail.com</CPEmail><HandCoverPrice></HandCoverPrice><PDFPrice>0.00</PDFPrice><PaperBackPrice></PaperBackPrice><EPubPrice></EPubPrice><BookImage>1.jpg</BookImage><Language>English</Language><ShippingCity>Karachi</ShippingCity><ShippingState>Sindh</ShippingState><ShippingCountry>Pakistan</ShippingCountry><BookUploadPath>EN161</BookUploadPath></Book><Book><BookID>263</BookID><BookCode>EN263</BookCode><BookTitle>A Call To Divine Unity</BookTitle><BookAuthor>Mansoor L Limba</BookAuthor><DatePublished>7/17/2003 12:00:00 AM</DatePublished><CPID>23</CPID><StatusID>287</StatusID><CPName>Kazim.Homayee</CPName><CPEmail>kazim.homayee@gmail.com</CPEmail><HandCoverPrice></HandCoverPrice><PDFPrice>0.00</PDFPrice><PaperBackPrice></PaperBackPrice><EPubPrice></EPubPrice><BookImage>1.jpg</BookImage><Language>English</Language><ShippingCity>Karachi</ShippingCity><ShippingState>Sindh</ShippingState><ShippingCountry>Pakistan</ShippingCountry><BookUploadPath>EN263</BookUploadPath></Book><Book><BookID>6</BookID><BookCode>EN6</BookCode><BookTitle>A Code of Practice for Muslims in the West</BookTitle><BookAuthor>Abdul Hadi al-Hakim</BookAuthor><DatePublished>3/16/2012 12:00:00 AM</DatePublished><CPID>23</CPID><StatusID>6</StatusID><CPName>Kazim.Homayee</CPName><CPEmail>kazim.homayee@gmail.com</CPEmail><HandCoverPrice></HandCoverPrice><PDFPrice>0.00</PDFPrice><PaperBackPrice></PaperBackPrice><EPubPrice></EPubPrice><BookImage>1.jpg</BookImage><Language>English</Language><ShippingCity>Karachi</ShippingCity><ShippingState>Sindh</ShippingState><ShippingCountry>Pakistan</ShippingCountry><BookUploadPath>EN6</BookUploadPath></Book><Book><BookID>9</BookID><BookCode>EN9</BookCode><BookTitle>A DIVINCE Perspective on Rights</BookTitle><BookAuthor>Ghodratullah Mashayekhi</BookAuthor><DatePublished>3/16/2012 12:00:00 AM</DatePublished><CPID>23</CPID><StatusID>16</StatusID><CPName>Kazim.Homayee</CPName><CPEmail>kazim.homayee@gmail.com</CPEmail><HandCoverPrice></HandCoverPrice><PDFPrice>0.00</PDFPrice><PaperBackPrice></PaperBackPrice><EPubPrice></EPubPrice><BookImage>1.jpg</BookImage><Language>English</Language><ShippingCity>Karachi</ShippingCity><ShippingState>Sindh</ShippingState><ShippingCountry>Pakistan</ShippingCountry><BookUploadPath>EN9</BookUploadPath></Book><Book><BookID>247</BookID><BookCode>EN247</BookCode><BookTitle>A Divine Perspective On Rights</BookTitle><BookAuthor>Imam Sajjad Ali ibn al-Hussein</BookAuthor><DatePublished>7/12/2008 12:00:00 AM</DatePublished><CPID>23</CPID><StatusID>950</StatusID><CPName>Kazim.Homayee</CPName><CPEmail>kazim.homayee@gmail.com</CPEmail><HandCoverPrice></HandCoverPrice><PDFPrice>0.00</PDFPrice><PaperBackPrice></PaperBackPrice><EPubPrice></EPubPrice><BookImage>1.jpg</BookImage><Language>English</Language><ShippingCity>Karachi</ShippingCity><ShippingState>Sindh</ShippingState><ShippingCountry>Pakistan</ShippingCountry><BookUploadPath>EN247</BookUploadPath></Book><Book><BookID>165</BookID><BookCode>EN165</BookCode><BookTitle>A Document of Instruction by Imam Ali (as)</BookTitle><BookAuthor>Anonymous</BookAuthor><DatePublished>5/18/2012 12:00:00 AM</DatePublished><CPID>23</CPID><StatusID>185</StatusID><CPName>Kazim.Homayee</CPName><CPEmail>kazim.homayee@gmail.com</CPEmail><HandCoverPrice></HandCoverPrice><PDFPrice>0.00</PDFPrice><PaperBackPrice></PaperBackPrice><EPubPrice></EPubPrice><BookImage>1.jpg</BookImage><Language>English</Language><ShippingCity>Karachi</ShippingCity><ShippingState>Sindh</ShippingState><ShippingCountry>Pakistan</ShippingCountry><BookUploadPath>EN165</BookUploadPath></Book><Book><BookID>12</BookID><BookCode>EN12</BookCode><BookTitle>A Probe into the History of Ashura</BookTitle><BookAuthor>Dr Ibrahim Ayati</B
```

- this XML data contains huge amount of data but i just need to access the data inside the `<BookTitle>` , `<BookCode>` and `<BookImage>` tags and display it in textVIew and in an imageVIew.
- and also i need some information about different types of parser available in android.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there are two approaches to parsing XML:

1. stream in the document one tag at a time and only process the tags that you are interested in
2. load the entire document into a hierarchical tree at once and then look up the nodes that you are interested in

Approach 1 is a lot more memory efficient, so is what the Android developer documentation suggests [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html).

Approach 2 typically is easier to get started on. But since it is less efficient, it is not the preferred approach and thus is a bit more hidden in the Android developer documentation. See this [API doc on the DocumentBuilderFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html) and [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/) to get started.

A snippet showing the crux:

```java
public Document parseXml(String xml) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder building = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource input = new InputSource();
    input.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
    return builder.parse(input); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks frank, thanks for your answer. from the above XML code i have to access the data contained in <BookID>,<BookCode>,<BookTitle> and <BookImage> tags only. Can u suggest me a little code please.

Comment: I'd start with a `getElementsByTagName` on the `Book` elements and work from there. If you're having problems, show us the code you have written and what problem it's giving.